# How to stop visual studio 2017 c++ from autocompleting ) while in the middle of FOR statement?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, editor

So every time I write something like

```
for (auto i = 0; i < my_vector.size();
```

the moment I add the semicolon after a function call in a for statement, it turns into

```
for (auto i = 0; i < my_vector.size());
```

and then I have to manually delete the automatic bracket close because I havent finished the for statement, super annoying.

I don't remember earlier VS versions doing this.

Anyway I tried going in options -> text editor -> c/c++ -> formatting -> general, I tried switching off "Automatically format statement when I type a ;" and also "Automatically format braces when they are automatically completed". Both had some minor effect but the problem I described was still happening.

I like autocomplete most of the time, I find it useful so I don't want to turn it off completely but how can I make it stop doing that one thing?

Comment: workaround: use for range: `for (auto& e : my_vector)` :-)

Comment: @Ron oh, guess I should update more often :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the Visual Studio. That particular (VS 2017) bug is [now fixed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27757/auto-complete-adds-parentheses-at-the-wrong-place.html) starting with the *VS 2017 15.4 Preview 2* update.